# Transforming ODEs into exact equations.

Tags: calculus, analysis, ordinary-differential-equations

I want some examples of ODEs that can only be solved by transforming them into exact equations. They shouldn't be solvable with; Direct integration, separation of variables, manipulating a reverse product rule, homogenous linear equation method, Bernoulli's equation, Laplace transform. What's the general formula for these kinds of equations?

This is an example DE that was solved by transforming it to an exact and taking it from there. Definitely not the best approach, as you can manipulate a reverse product rule or even simpler solve it as a separable one. What I want is a DE that can ONLY be solved analytically by transforming it in an exact one and has no other possible methods. Anyway, here goes;

$(x+3)y'= x y(x) \iff  
-(x y(x))+(x+3)y'(x)= 0$

Let $R(x, y)=-xy$ and $S(x, y)  =  x+3$.
$R(x, y)_y  =  -x \not= 1  =  S(x, y)_x$

To transform it into exact;

$(m(x) R(x, y))_y  =  (m(x) S(x, y))_x    \iff
-(x m(x))  =  m(x)_x (x+3)+m(x) \iff    \frac{m(x)_x}{m(x)}  =  -\frac{x+1}{x+3} \iff \ln(m(x))  =  -x+2 ln(x+3) \iff m(x)  =  \frac{(x+3)^2}{e^x} \iff -\frac{x (x+3)^2 y(x)}{e^x}+(x+3)^3 \frac{y'}{e^x}  =  0$

Let $P(x, y)  =  -e^{-x} x (x+3)^2 y$ and $Q(x, y)  =  e^{-x} (x+3)^3$.

This is an exact equation; $P(x, y)_y  =  -e^{-x} x (x+3)^2  =  Q(x, y)_x$.

Let $f(x, y)$ such that $f(x, y)_x  =  P(x, y)$  and $f(x, y)_y  =  Q(x, y)$

Then, the solution will be given by $f(x, y)  =  c_1$

Ergo $f(x, y)  =   \int -\frac{y x (x+3)^2}{e^x} dx  =  \frac{y (x+3)^3}{e^x}+g(y)$, $g(y)$ is a function of $y$ that we could have lost due to partial differentiation.

And $f(x, y)_y  =  \frac{y (x+3)^3}{e^x}+g(y)_y  =     \frac {(x+3)^3}{e^x}+g(y)_y$

Substituting into $f(x, y)_y  =  Q(x, y)$:

$\frac{(x+3)^3}{e^x}+g(y)_y  =  \frac{(x+3)^3}{e^x}  \iff
g(y)_y  =  0 \iff g(y)  =   \int 0 dy  =  0$
Thus $\frac{y (x+3)^3}{e^x}  =  c_1$
$y(x) = \frac{c_1 e^x}{(x+3)^3}$.

Comment: Did you mean numerical methods?

Comment: All the methods mentioned above are analytical.

Comment: I mean: do you want to get an information about equations which can be solved only numerically? It's well-known that numerical methods transform an ODE in such way that we solve algebraic equations without any of methods mentioned above.

Comment: I'm trying to understand what I didn't make clear in my first post to create confusion. This has nothing to do with numerical methods, and I don't know how to phrase this more clearly; I want examples of ODEs that MUST be transformed to EXACT EQUATIONS to be ANALYTICALLY solved.

Comment: I think you'll need to provide an example of what you're looking for. As it stands, your intention simply isn't clear since you want it to be analytically solvable while disallowing most of the tools for doing so.

Comment: Well, here's my way of thinking. I've met a fair amount of ODEs and some of them could be transformed and solved as exact ones. However, all of these that could be transformed to exact DEs had a simpler and faster solution with another method. So I was wondering if there is any ODE that can't be solved with anything but being transformed into an exact equation. The example you want me to provide is what I am looking for.

Comment: Well, its not obvious to me that any method of finding exact solutions will be truly general. So a somewhat different question might br more fruitful: "What are some techniques for finding exact solutions which are not part of the standard toolbox listed in your OP?" The method of Lie algebraization of the ODE would be an example of such.

Comment: You guys all got it wrong. I'm not looking for exact numerical solution of an ODE, I'm looking for exact differential equations(in fact I'm looking for non-exact that can only be solved by transforming them into exact DEs). http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exact_differential_equation

Comment: Total differential equation -- this is general name. And I could not understand what you wanted. This is a small group, and here you are totally wrong! This equation is solved in the same way as separation of variables -- it is integrated. To make sure, consider an equality $$dU=0 .$$ Next step will be an integration, and it's irrelevant what is under $U$. So, you solve with integration and don't know that it's integration!

Comment: I'll provide an example of what I mean.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These equations are called equations which demand an integrating multiplier. They are solved by searching integrating multiplier and transforming to total DE (exact, as you call). There is no general form of these equations, but, if you want, you can come up with any cumbersome nonlinear function $F(x,y)$ and a multiplier (this is only one of many possible) $m(x)=x^{\alpha}, \alpha>1$ or $m(y)=y^{\alpha}, \alpha>1$ and obtain an equation in a following way: consider a one-parametric family of curves
$$F(x,y)=C ,$$
multiply by $m(x)$(for instance)
$$m(x)F(x,y)=C ,$$
and differentiate it:
$$\frac{\partial m F}{\partial x}dx+\frac{\partial m F}{\partial y}dy=0 $$
$$\left(x^{\alpha -1}F+x^{\alpha}\frac{\partial F}{\partial x}\right)dx+x^{\alpha}\frac{\partial F}{\partial y}dy.$$
After dividing by $x^{\alpha-1}$ we obtain very cumbersome equation, it can be transformed to what you want, and if $F(x,y)$ is very cumbersome, this equation can't be solved with another method with probability almost 1. Everything depends here on your imagination.

Comment: I know what they are and how to solve them. What I want to know is if there exists a differential equation that requires an integrating factor so it becomes total AND  that equation must not have any other way to solve it analyticaly(with other methods). Plus I forgot to say that the function we seek should have one variable only. Sorry for not pointing that out earlier.

PS: Finally someone understood what I wanted, how would you formulate the same question but with the one variable only requirement?

Comment: I take it you mean one variable equation (ODE), you can see something like
$$Adx+Bdy=0 $$
If you rewrite it as
$$\frac{dy}{dx}=-\frac{A}{B} ,$$
then it will be a one-variable equation
$$y'=\frac{-A}{B} ,$$
where $y=y(x)$ and we have an ODE.

Comment: AND it should ONLY be solvable by transforming it into a total DE. How do I create these?

Comment: Take (for example) a weird function $F(x,y)=\ln\cos\frac{x+e^y}{\sin \sqrt{x^2+y}}+...$. The more $F$ is weird, the less is a chance that simple method can solve it. There is no special algorithm for obtaining such functions

Comment: One variable, but thanks, just wondered if there is any general formula to generate them.